# Change detection not happening after rxjs subject emits value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm not sure why change detection is not running in the case described below. My app is written in Ionic (v6.20.1) with Angular(14+)

I've read this: https://angular.io/guide/zone
, but I still don't see why it's not occuring.

Can someone clarify this please?

app.component.ts:

```
setupAppStateChange() {
  App.addListener('appStateChange', async ({ isActive }) => {
   if (!isActive) return

   if (this.location.isCurrentPathEqualTo('/wallet')) {
     this.walletService.refreshAmount()
   }
}
```

Note: change detection works if i do this, but i want to understand why it's needed:

```
   this.zone.run(async () => {
      this.walletService.refreshAmount()
   })
```

wallet.service.ts:

```
private _amount: number
private _amountChanged: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>()

async refreshAmount() {
    const wallet: Wallet = await Parse.Cloud.run('getWallet')
    this._amount = wallet.balance
    this._amountChanged.next(this._amount)
}
```

wallet.page.ts:

```
private subscribeAmountChanged() {
    this.availableAmountChanged = this.walletService.amountChanged.subscribe({
      next: async (value) => {
        //hide topup screen
        this.isTopUp = false

        if (this.availableAmount != value) {
          //set new amount
          this.availableAmount = value

          //reset history list
          await this.loadFirstHistoryPage()
        }
      },
    })
 }
```

Comment: The reason you need to run the function for it to work is because it is in the function that you call the subject's next. Without calling the function, the subject does not get any updated values.

Comment: That's incorrect, the code block in subscribe is called correctly (without the zone.run function), i've tested this

Comment: Oh I am so sorry, didn't see there you had an event that was triggering it. Well then the reason is because the event handler is not handled by/in the zone. This means Angular's change detection cannot be triggered, as it is not informed that something happend. Using zone.run makes part of your script run inside the zone which can then succesfully inform Angular of the changes.

Comment: But why is it not handled by/in the zone... According to the documentation described in the question, async operations trigger change detection, but receiving a value from a subject is async? so it should happen correctly?

Comment: It is not in the zone because App.addListener('appStateChange' does not run handlers in the zone context. As to all the behind the scene why's, I cannot explain exactly. Please read the docs, they explicitely say you should run inside the zone. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/angular

Comment: Will do, thanks for helping out!